Asymptotic approximation of Stirling numbers of the second kind
It is well known the asymptotic approximation of Stirling numbers of the second kind to be
$$S(n,k) \sim \frac{k^n}{k!} \ \ \text{as} \ \ \ \ n\rightarrow \infty $$
but Is it possible to comment on how large $n$ should be (from perhaps considering the next order term in this limit) compared to $k$ for this to hold. I tried to look into some references given here, but didn't find (or couldn't understand) anything.

Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind for a better (but much more complex asymptotics.   https://mathoverflow.net/questions/162764/understanding-a-particular-approximation-for-stirlings-number-of-the-second-kind is useful

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/270473525_Asymptotics_of_the_Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind_revisited

That approximation is quite crude, and only useful for $n \gg k$.
It has a simple probabilistic interpretation: we can write
$$S(n,k) = \frac {k^n}{k!} p(n,k)$$
where $p(n,k)$ is the probability that, if we place $n$ balls in $k$ urns with uniform probability, no urn is empty. The approximation amounts to assuming the probability is almost one, which should be reasonable if $n$ is "large enough"... with respect to $k$.
One can try some better approximation (and, hopefully, some information about when the zero order approximation holds), thus: The balls in each urn follow a Binomial distribution with parameters $(n, 1/k)$. They are not independent, but if $k,n$ are large enough we may assume approximate independence:
$$p(n,k) \approx \left( 1 - (1 -1/k)^n  \right)^k$$
If we want $p(n,k) \approx 1 - \epsilon$ for, say $\epsilon=0.05$, that implies $$ n \approx \frac{\log(1- (1-\epsilon)^{1/k})}{\log(1-1/k)}$$
Again, if $k,n$ are large enough, we can approximate further:
$$p(n,k) \approx  \left( 1 - e^{-n/k} \right)^k \approx \exp \left( - k \cdot e^{-n/k}\right)$$
Again, if we set $p(n,k) \approx 1 - \epsilon$ that implies $$ n \approx k \log (k/\epsilon)$$
Numerically, it seems to give reasonable results. For example, for that relative error target ($\sim 5\%$) we'd get the $(n,k)$ pairs: $(23,5)$ , $(35,7)$ $(60,11)$ $(120,20)$.

A much more precise approximation, that works well also for both $n,k$ are large, is given here (it includes my derivation). But it's not very simple.
$$\begin{align}
S_{n,k} &\approx  {n \choose k} \frac{(n-k)!}{\sqrt{2\pi n (\lambda - v +1)}}\frac{(e^\lambda -1)^k}{\lambda^n} \tag 1\\
&\approx \left( \frac{n}{ e \cdot \lambda} \right)^n
\left( \frac{e^{\lambda +1} \cdot \lambda}{ n} \right)^k
\sqrt{\frac{v}{2\pi n (\lambda - v +1)}} \tag 2
\end{align}
$$
where $v=n/k$ and $\lambda$ is the positive root of
$$\lambda = (1-e^{-\lambda}) \frac{n}{k}  $$
which can be written as $\lambda= h(v)=v+ W(-v \, e^{-v})$ where $W()$ is the Lambert-W function.
Here's a graph of approximation $(2)$ vs the exact values and the crude approximation, for $n=10$ and several values of $k$. Values in logaritmic scale.
It can be seen that the approximation $S(n,k) \sim \frac{k^n}{k!} $ works only for $k\ll n$.
Same for $n=30$.


Thanks! The first expression that you wrote, that's exactly was part of my problem. I wanted to know how large $k$ should be in terms of $n$ so that $p(n,k)\rightarrow 1$. It seems it's $n = k\log(k/\epsilon)$.

Great. Bear in mind, though, that $S_{n,k}$ grows rapidly, hence the relative error might not be very useful (one might argue that's it's more appropiate to measure the relative error of the logarithms...)

Also, the previous expression $n=\frac{\log(1- (1-\epsilon)^{1/k})}{\log(1-1/k)}$ might be more precise, especially if $k$ is small.

Hi, Can you say again on what exactly do you mean by measuring the relative error of the logarithms?

The simplest approximation I saw (and use) is, for $k < \frac n {\log(n)}$,
$$S(n,k) \sim \frac {k^n}{k!}\,\exp\Bigg( \left(\frac{n}{k}-k\right) e^{-\frac{n}{k}}\Bigg)$$
The problem is that I do not find where I found it (I suppose that it is from Erdos's group).
